# Snub nose bike saddles

Tags: saddle

I need to replace my bike saddle, a Most Ocelot that came with the bike, because the supporting rib (not the rails) broke about four inches from the nose, and it is starting to sag.  I'm only 145 lbs.  I am interested in a snub nose saddle, but in current circumstances, I can't visit a bike store, and I am interested in riders' experience with this style.  I mostly ride in the drops on 2 - 4 hour rides.  I'm not a racer.

Anybody have experience with these?

TIA

Comment: Sounds like it was faulty - if the bike is newish, start a warranty claim.  Saddle breaking is not impossible but a relatively rare event.

Comment: I put one on my bike when I brought it into the trainer last fall. I don’t really notice that it’s missing the nose unless I’m riding on the rivet, which I do sometimes because that damn zwift makes leisurely rides impossible. I won’t keep it on the bike when spring finally gets here and I get back outside because I do think the front of the saddle is important for other things, like squeezing with my legs on downhills, or controlling the bike when things go not-as-planned like hitting a pothole or getting forced off the road. Those last two two things can’t really be tested though.

Comment: The saddle (and rider) have 40,000 miles on it, but I still think it should not have broken.  That has never happened to me before over 55 years of riding.

Comment: Interesting comment about needing the nose for control.  That's the sort of concern that I have.

Comment: If you ride mostly in the drops, maybe you should lower your handlebar? Use the drops when you really need them.

Answer (score 5):

There are several companies making "noseless" saddles as well as snub nosed saddles.  Either will "work", as in, you can use them to ride a bike.  I had several riding friends who swore by the Spongey Wonder in particular.  I tried it and found that while it was possible to use, it wasn't for me.  These seats are sold with the idea that they don't contact the perineum and won't do damage to nerves or vasculature there.

A nose breaking on a saddle is fairly rare.  I have seen far more broken rails or shells than I have ever seen broken noses.  As mentioned in comments, I'd likely seek a warranty replacement if this was on a new saddle.

As for needing the presence of a nose, strictly speaking, it is not necessary to ride a bike.  However, it is an extra control surface that can be used in various positions to exert or maintain control of a bicycle.  That being said, I always prefer to ride a saddle that DOES have a nose.

TL;DR  If you have nerve or vascular concerns and have had issues with nosed seats, a snub nose or noseless saddle may be worth investigating.  If you are simply concerned with the idea of a nose breaking again, I would say it's a low probability event and not worth investigating alternate saddle designs over.

Comment: Having had many seats over the decades with no problem, I was quite surprised that this one broke.  I thought a noseless saddle would be more comfortable, but I don't have nerve/vascular concerns.  I wouldn't want to give up the control, however.

Answer (score 0):

There are ["dual pad" seats](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/saddles.html#split) which most people find less than comfortable, but a few like:

[image]

I've also seen, maybe 30 years ago, a sort of hammock seat, with two rails spaced about 10 inches apart, one on each side, and a cloth/leather hammock-like piece running between the rails:

[image]

And several vendors sell seats with a sort of opening or channel down the center, to relieve pressure on "sensitive parts".

Comment: I guess I will wait until bike shops reopen and hope to try out alternatives, although none of the shops here carry many models.